# Learning&Practicing Domain Driven Design, Looking for some guidance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am currently working towards learning "Domain Driven Design".

I'm wondering how someone would design these entities. I simplified the object model as it would take to long to explain the "REAL" application to highlight the area of the domain I'm having trouble with.

So a CustomerInfo aggregate contains a list of Entries. It's this "Entry" object I'm having trouble designing.

```
//Lets call the CustomerInfo the Aggregate Root
public class CustomerInfo {
    /* Other properties removed, to simplify question */

    public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

}
```

The Entry object "can" be described by a few different lists of entities. The caveat here is the "Entry" can "ONLY" be described by one of these lists. In my domain it does not make sense for an entry to have a list of Widgets AND a list of ThisThings.

To complicate things. 
The entities **Trinket**, **ThatThing**, **ThisThing** and **TheOtherThing** all have the same properties, but in the context of this domain their meaning is very different.

This is my current domain model. Which I do not like as I have all this validation to make sure only one of the lists are populated by the user

```
public class Entry
 {
    public Guid EntryId { get; set; }

    /* Other properties removed, to simplify question */

    public List<Widget> Widget { get; set; } 

    public List<Trinket> Trinkets { get; set; }
    public List<ThatThing> ThatThings { get; set; }
    public List<ThisThing> ThisThings { get; set; }
    public List<TheOtherThing> TheOtherThings { get; set; } 
 }


 public class Widget
 {
    public Guid Widgetid { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
 }

 public class Trinket
 {
    public Guid Trinketid { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class ThatThing
 {
    public Guid ThatThingid { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class ThisThing
 {
    public Guid ThisThingid { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class TheOtherThing
 {
    public Guid TheOtherThingId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class Construction : ValueObject<Construction>
 {
    public int Size { get; private set; }
    public string Weight { get; private set; }
    public string Unit { get; private set; }
    public string Form { get; private set; }
 }
```

What I'm struggling with is how to model this "Entry" entity properly.

1) Should I keep as designed and just rely on this crazy validation.

2) Should I be creating a polymorphic model to handle these?

```
public interface IWidget{
      public Guid Widgetid { get; set; }

}

public interface IDifferentWidget:IWidget
{

    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; set; }
}

public class Widget:IWidget
 {
    public Guid WidgetId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
 }

 public class Trinket : IDifferentWidget
 {
    public Guid WidgetId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class ThatThing : IDifferentWidget
 {
    public Guid WidgetId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class ThisThing : IDifferentWidget
 {
    public Guid WidgetId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }

 public class TheOtherThing : IDifferentWidget
 {
    public Guid WidgetId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; private set; }
    public Construction Construction { get; private set; }
 }
```

Then the Entry entity would look like, but does not prevent a **ThisThing** and **ThatThing** being added to the same Entry List.

```
public class Entry
 {
    public Guid EntryId { get; set; }

    /* Other properties removed, to simplify question */

    public List<IWidget> Widgets { get; set; } 

 }
```

3) Should I create different Entry entities entirely like  WidgetEntry, ThisThingEntry with a common interface so the Aggregate Root would look like so:

```
 //Lets call the CustomerInfo the Aggregate Root
public class CustomerInfo {
/* Other properties removed, to simplify question */

   public List<IEntry> Entries { get; set; }

 }
```

Considering the different options I've contemplated,the only solution that tackles this domain constraint **"Entry" can "ONLY" be described by one of these lists** is #3

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, apologizes for the long winded question!

/*******************************REVISED DOMAIN DESIGN ***********************/

I still believe an **CustomerInfo** should be the aggregate because in my domain it makes sense to describe the **CustomerInfo** by the various entries users add to it to build a "CustomerInfo" entity.

```
//Lets call the CustomerInfo the Aggregate Root
public class CustomerInfo {

    public Guid CustomerId { get; private set; }

    private List<Entry> _entries;
    public IEnumerable<Entry> Entries => _entries;

    private CustomerInfo(Guid customerId /* Other properties removed, to 
    simplify question */){  }

    public CustomerInfo Create(/* Other properties removed, to simplify 
                                 question       */) {
    return new CustomerInfo(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

    /*This is how the entity will control the state of the various lists of 
    entities that describe it.*/
    public Entry UpdateEntry(/* Parameters removed for simplicity */)   {

    }

    public Entry AddEntry(/* Parameters removed for simplicity */)  {

    }

    public Entry RemoveEntry(/* Parameters removed for simplicity */)   {

    }
   }



public class Entry {
     public Guid EntryId { get; set; }

    /* Other properties removed, to simplify question */
    private List<Widget> _widgets;
    public IEnumerable<Widget> Widgets => _widgets;

    private List<Trinket> _trinkets;
    public IEnumerable<Trinket> Trinkets => _trinkets;

    private List<ThatThing> _thatThing;
    public IEnumerable<ThatThing> ThatThings => _thatThing;

    private List<ThisThing> _thisThings;
    public IEnumerable<ThisThing> ThisThings => _thisThings;

    private List<TheOtherThing> _theOtherThing;
    public IEnumerable<TheOtherThing> TheOtherThings => _theOtherThing;


    private Entry(guid EntryId /*This constructor will take more parameters,        
    it's simplified for my question*/)  {   }

    //Create a new instance of a Entry entity
    public Entry Create(/* Parameters removed for simplicity */) {
        return new Entry(Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    //This is how the entity will control the state of the various lists of         
     entities that describe it.
    public Widget UpdateWidget()    {

    }

    public Widget AddWidget() {

    }

    public Widget RemoveWidget()    {

    }

    private bool CanAddAWidget() {
        /* Logic to prevent a widget from being add if any of the other         
            lists have items*/
    }

    public ThisThing UpdateThisThing()
    {

    }

    public ThisThing AddThisThing()
    {

    }

    public ThisThing RemoveThisThing()
    {

    }

    private bool CanAddAThisThing()
    {
    /* Logic to prevent a widget from being add if any of the other lists       
  have items*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this question a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You are sort of describing an EF inheritance model called Table per Concrete Type (TPC). You can define a class inheritance and share code in the base class, but each class is actually backed by its own database table (the shared schema is copied into each table). If you want to learn more about it: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.

Comment: Hi Pedro, you could apply this to TPC but that's not really what my question is regarding. Data Persistence is not a concern here. I'm just focusing on Domain Modelling, but thank you for the input..it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't designed a proper `Aggregate root` - a tactical `Domain driven design` pattern.

In your case, `Entry` should be an `Aggregate root` that ensures its own invariants. The invariant that I've identified is that `Entry` should not have only one kind of `Thing` added to its internal list. So, your code should reflect that invariant.

That being said, the `Entry` should have an **private** list of things, implemented as separate lists or just one mixed list, depending on the list/lists usage. That will prevent the client code to add items to the list without any verification. Then the `Aggregate` should have a `addThing` public method (replace that name with a more proper name from your `Ubiquitous language`). This method must verify the said invariant and reject any duplicates.

To use or not an `abstraction` depends not on DDD but on the usage of the `Things`. Ask yourself: does this abstraction help me to follow the OOP principles (see [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)))? In your case is not clear because I don't know how you use those `things` inside the `Aggregate` or in the client code.

Comment: Constantin thanks for the input! Updated my question with a revised domain model. You'll see that now an "Entry" fully controls the Widgets and "Things" lists... What do you think?    As far as SOLID goes, these entities way heavier on the "Data Representation" side opposed the type of entity that "Does Something" Like a PrintJob or Scheduler class. I guess I could say they are mostly CRUD operations.   I do have some functionality but it is mostly in the "Entry" class... the "Widget" and "Things"  entities will be used in the Entry class to help with a calculation but  that's really it.

Comment: @GregL That's more like it! Just remeber, Aggregates do not permit their state to become invalid. They ensure this by making mutable properties as `private` and with carefully chosen named methods that access those properties.

Comment: Thank you sir!!! So great to have a community to bounce ideas off!!! I am finding it challenging to make the shift to this way of thinking and away from "Data Focused" entities, but I am finding I actually enjoy designing this way!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't abstract away your question like this. For example what makes a Widget and a ThisThing so simmilar that they can be listed together but a ThatThing can't be?

Just consider it like this

```
class Dog: IMamal {

}

class Cat: IMamal {
}

interface IMamal : IAnimal {

}

class Chicken : IAnimal {
}
```

Here i found that Dogs and Cats are simmilar in that if i talk about animals that i would refer to those kind of animals as mamals.

So talk to your domain expert and try to figure out what certain groups of things are called. That way you can define an interface that groups certain things together but not others

If you can't find a way why they belong together in by talking to your domain expert then  it's a good bet they should be 2 separate lists.

Polimorphism should really only follow if your domain really describes it that way. If i take my animal example a Mamal might have a Walk() method and a Bird might have a Fly() method and a Hop() method (if a birt doesn't fly)
There might not be polymorphic Move() method since no biologist would describe that an animal moves, they always refer to it as either walking or flying (just for the sake of argument here, it should be the domain expert who describes entities as all having a "Name" and not the programmer who sees that "Name" "Label" and "Description" are the same kind of fields. (As Mike pointed out conincidental coheision is the thing to avoid here)

Comment: Thank you Batavia, your last paragraph really helped me think about this another way... Just because an "Entry" could have a list of Widgets or list of ThatThings but not both is more of a business rule than a "domain model" concept. My domain expert could not come up with a meaningful name to categorize the (Trinket, ThatThing, ThisThing and TheOtherThings) together so that should have told me that even though these entities have the same "field types" and names..they actually represent different domain entities in this context.

Comment: I'd like also to add that forcing classes to follow common interface might easily lead to "coincidental cohesion", where different classes have some common code which shouldn't really be there. Coincidental cohesion is considered the worst type of cohesion in modules.